# AngularJS: I can't view the scope created in the get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, http-get

I've done two controllers:

One is a **UsersCtrl** where I do a `$http.get()` and I take all the users from a json. And when you click in on a User, you go in another page with another Controller (**UsersDetailCtrl**), where I've to use the `$stateParams.id` passed via the url, (that is ok) and check if there is an id which match in the `$http.get`.

I show you my `UsersDetailCtrl` and then I tell you my problem:

```
.controller('UsersDetailCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicModal, $window, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {
console.log($stateParams.id);
        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
          animation: 'fade-in',
          showDelay: 0,
          showBackdrop: true
    });
    var urlUtenti  = "users.json";
    $http.get(urlUtenti).success(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            if (response[i].id == $stateParams.id) {
                $scope.user = response[i];
            }
          }
        $timeout(function(){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        },1000);
        })
    console.log($scope.user);
})
```

Into the `$http.get`, precisely into the `for clause`, I have a `$scope.user = response[i]` where If I do a `console.log(response[i])` or `console.log($scope.user)` **INTO** the `for clause` it's correct, I receive the Object that I want, **BUT** as you can see below, I've put the `console.log($scope.user)` in the end of the controller because I need to use that scope in the html view.
The Result? `undefined`.

So why into the for clause it's all right and out of the http get it's not?
How can I do to use the `$scope.user` in my html view?

P.S. I've already tried to make the scope an object and it return me a empty object.. same thing for the array. What is wrong with the scope?

Thanks.

Comment: try a "$scope.$apply()" after your "$scope.user = response[i];"

Comment: Your `console.log($scope.user)` is outside the `$http.get` so it will happen before the request is resolved. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. Also, why are you overwriting the `$scope.user` with each iteration of `response`?

Comment: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress` already tried. :)

Comment: @KaranKumar no, that will most likely result in an error saying a digest cycle is already in progress.

Comment: @Phil already tried to put into the `$http.get` the console and I'm not overwriting the scope because it is into a `if clause`. There is only one `ID` that correspond to the `$stateParams.id`

Comment: `console.log($scope.user)` have this after your for loop.

Comment: @LudovicoLoreti oops, I missed the `if`. Is there an actual problem? What you have should work fine. When the HTTP request is resolved and one of your responses matches the ID, `$scope.user` will be set which should be shown in any HTML views

Comment: If you want to log the user record once it's been found, do it just after the `for` loop (before the `$timeout` call), eg `console.log('$scope.user', $scope.user)`. I'd also `break` after finding the user so you don't do needless iterations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) commented, `$scope.user` is set just fine (if there is one matching `$stateParams.id`, that is) - your "problem" in the `console.log($scope.user)` logging `undefined` is that it is executed too early.

The flow goes like this:

- `$http.get(urlUtenti).success(successFunction)` -> HTTP GET starts executing **asynchronously**
- `console.log($scope.user)` (outside `successFunction`) -> executes immediately (`successFunction` hasn't yet been invoked, so `$scope.user` is undefined at this point)
- HTTP GET returns successfully -> `successFunction` is executed and `$scope.user` is set.

Try this:

```
.controller('UsersDetailCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicModal, $window, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {
    console.log($stateParams.id);
    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showDelay: 0,
        showBackdrop: true
    });
    var urlUtenti  = "users.json";
    $http.get(urlUtenti).success(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            if (response[i].id == $stateParams.id) {
                $scope.user = response[i];
            }
        }
        // console.log moved INSIDE the success function (before timeout)
        console.log($scope.user);
        $timeout(function(){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        },1000);
    })
})
```